# Is it possible to track analytics on an offline swf?

Tags: flash, actionscript, google-analytics, analytics

The user is downloading the .swf file (an e-brochure) from a link in an email. I'm trying to track the users interaction on the offline .swf. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how they view the SWF file (in a browser?), whether they have Internet connectivity, and their security settings, but you could likely do analytics the same way email campaigns do - have the SWF load an image from a server using a URLRequest and a Loader, then count the number of image views on the server side.